# How do I do Ctrl-Left-Click operations in GIMP on Mac OS X?

Tags: gimp

When you <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ left-Click, it's like a right-click in Mac OS X and brings up a menu.

I'm trying to clone a selected rectangle as [shown here](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-using-selections.html)

But if I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+ click, I just get a context menu because Mac OS X is thinking I'm right-clicking.

How do I do this? I know I can copy/paste/move. But I want the shortcut method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+ click on the Mac

Windows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> = Mac <kbd>Command</kbd> (Apple key) 
Windows <kbd>Alt</kbd> = Mac <kbd>Option</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. The one combination of keys I didn't try. :)